# UncaughtAssertionError:expected promise to be rejected with error including 'Falsy value' but was fulfilled with {Object(_idleTimeout,_idlePrev, ...)}

Tags: javascript, promise

Writing a function which creates and returns a promise.

> Run a given (callback) function after a delay.
> However:

- if the given callback returns a falsy value, the promise should fail (reject)
  the string "Falsy value retrieved" should be sent through to the reject function
- if the given callback returns a truthy value, the promise should pass (resolve)
  the return value of the executed callback should be sent through to the resolve function

```
const doShortlyExpectingTruthy = function(callback, delay, data) {
  const promise =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let returnValue = setTimeout(callback, delay, data);
    if (returnValue) {
      resolve(returnValue);
    } else if (!returnValue) {
      reject("Falsy value");
    }
  });
  return promise;
};
```

May I know how to fix this Uncaught Assertion Error.

Comment: `setTimeout()` immediately returns an identifier to the timeout callback to be executed at a later time. So `if (returnValue)` is immediately `true`... Nothing waits for the timeout to be executed after the `delay`.

Answer (score 0):

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)'s return value is an integer id used to cancel the timeout, not the return value of the callback. If `setTimeout` worked synchronously like this, there'd be no need for the promise.

I'd break out a generic `sleep` function to keep the `new Promise` constructor out of your code, then use `async`/`await`. `throw` in an `async` function is the same as calling `reject`.

```js
const sleep = ms => 
  new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))
;

const doShortlyExpectingTruthy = async (fn, delay, ...args) => {
  await sleep(delay);
  const res = fn(...args);
  
  if (!res) {
    throw Error("Falsy value retrieved");
  }
  
  return res;
};

(async () => {
  console.log(await doShortlyExpectingTruthy(v => v, 1000, 42));
  await doShortlyExpectingTruthy(v => v, 1000, 0);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
;
```